# How do I plot the output of numpy.fft in bins?

Tags: pandas, numpy, fft

I wrote some python code that plots the fast fourier transform of a pandas `DataFrame` called `res`, which contains two columns of data ("data" and "filtered"):

```
fft = pd.DataFrame(np.abs(np.fft.rfft(res["data"])))
fft.columns = ["data"]
fft["filtered"] = pd.DataFrame(np.abs(np.fft.rfft(res["filtered"])))

fft.index=np.fft.fftfreq(len(res))[0:len(fft)]
fft.plot(logy=True, logx=True)
```

The `res` dataset contains some original randomised datapoints in the "data" column along with the same data after passing through a filter. The output looks reasonable to me;

[image]

While this plot is probably correct, it's not very useful to look at. How can I organise this data into a smaller number of discrete frequency bins to make it easier to understand?

Comment: [pd.cut](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) might help you to organize your data in bins.... You can also try to downsample your data and calculate an average (this might "spoil" short-peaks) or you can try to plot `np.log()`...

Comment: btw, i reckon you meant `np.abs(np.fft.rfft(res["data"]))` instead of `np.abs(np.fft.rfft(res["data"]).real)`, to get the amplitude of the relevant frequencies (though I meant be wrong).

Comment: @tmrlvi I think you're right - I've amended it. Cheers.

Comment: You can always use [`np.histogram`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) to compute a histogram of your power spectrum using a logarithmic set of bin limits, but I can't say how that might or might not bias your computed spectrum (and whether or not you should work with your raw spectrum or with logarithms).

Comment: @AndrasDeak can you answer the question with an usage example of np.histogram?

Comment: @Guglie OK, so what I sort of had in mind (2 years ago, without giving it much thought back then) is to cut up the `x` data using logarithmic histogram bins and _average_ the values that fall inside a bin, something like `logbins = np.geomspace(data_x.min(), data_x.max(), nbins+1)` then `np.histogram(data_x, bins=logbins, weights=data_y)` and dividing by the histogram counts for an average (just taking care to get the edge points right, which my example probably doesn't). Now I'm not sure that this makes much sense, some more robust smoothing process is probably more preferable.

Comment: @AndrasDeak thanks! By the way I meant if you want to create an answer with sample code I'll surely upvote :)

Comment: @Guglie thanks, but the question is missing an MCVE and I don't feel like trying to hack together an example (which is also why I only left a comment 2 years ago ;)